# Cartopy: Convert point from axes coordinates to lat/lon coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am working on a map plot with Cartopy (`TransverseMercator` projection). I have a point in axes coordinates (`p_a = (0.1, 0.9)`) and I need its lat/lon coordinates (i.e., those in `PlateCarree` projection). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you need to transform the point from axes coordinates to display coordinates, then to data coordinates, and finally to lat/ lon coordinates. Thus you need transformations from [matplotlib](http://%20https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) and [cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/crs/index.html#cartopy.crs.CRS.transform_point).

The point `p_a = (0.1, 0.9)` seems to be outside of valid lat/ lon coordinates (for the default `ccrs.TransverseMercator()`). Therefore I use `p_a = (0.6, 0.6)`

```python
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

proj = ccrs.TransverseMercator()
proj_cart = ccrs.PlateCarree() 

f, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj))
ax.coastlines()

# define point
p_a = (0.6, 0.6)

# plot point in Axes coordinates
ax.plot(*p_a, transform=ax.transAxes, marker='o', ms=10)

# convert from Axes coordinates to display coordinates
p_a_disp = ax.transAxes.transform(p_a)

# convert from display coordinates to data coordinates
p_a_data = ax.transData.inverted().transform(p_a_disp)

# convert from data to cartesian coordinates
p_a_cart = proj_cart.transform_point(*p_a_data, src_crs=proj)

# make sure we are correct
ax.plot(*p_a_cart, transform=proj_cart, marker='x', ms=10)
```

This yields the following figure:

[image: original and transformed point]